# Accessing a Filter object through a WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to call a method on a `Filter` object after it has been added according to the `web.xml` definition. All I got is a `WebApplicationContext` object (let's call it: `wac`).

- I'm able to add new Filter objects via: `wac.getServletContext().addFilter("otherfilter", otherFilter);`
- Also, I can test successfully for its existence via: `wac.getServletContext().getFilterRegistration("myfilter")`

But how may I access (and possibly modify) `Filter` objects which have been added before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it exactly as you want, but this problem is usually solved using different approach.

You can declare your `Filter` as a bean in your application context and then register a [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) in `web.xml` to delegate filtering to your filter.

In this case your filter will be a regular Spring bean, and you'll be able to access it like any other bean.

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet API does not provide any mechanism to directly access a `Filter` instance once it has been added to a `ServletContext`. The best you are going to get with the Servlet API is the `FilterRegistration` interface you have already found which lets you modify the same set of configuration options as you can via web.xml.

Depending on exactly what you want to do, you might be able to code your way around this problem using init parameters but that is never going to be a particularly clean solution. I'd go with the `DelegatingFilterProxy` solution suggested by axtavt.